# How to filter values in objects of array in angular

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

How to filter values in objects of the array in angular.
(example: I need to filter values in the staff object of staffAttendanceList, I don't know how to pass the correct parameter to filter the staff values.)

Typescript

1)In .ts:

```
   attendanceStatus:any;
   staffAttendanceList: StaffAttendance[] = [
      status:false,
      staff:{
       staffId:"ERP1001",
       firstName:'Rahul',
       lastName:'Sharma'
       }
     ];
```

HTML: I have used filter pipe with parameter ('staff'), but it is not working.

2) In HTML:

```
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr*ngFor="let staffAttendance of staffAttendanceList|filter:searchStaffAttendance:'staff.staffId';
        index as i">
          <td>{{i+1}}</td>
          <td>{{staffAttendance.staff.staffId}} 
          </td>
          <td>{{staffAttendance.staff.firstName}} 
           {{staffAttendance.staff.lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Filter pipe: I have created a custom filter pipe to search for staff values.

3)In Filter pipe:

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
    name:'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform = (value:[],filterString:any,propName:any):any => { 
        let inputValue = [];
        if(filterString === undefined || filterString === '' || 
           value.length == 0){
            return value;
        }
        for(const item of value){
            if(item[propName] === filterString){
                inputValue.push(item);
            }          
        }
        return inputValue;
    }      
}
```

Comment: item[propName] is trying to access item[staff.staffId] which doesnt exist in your object.

Comment: Worth a read: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a for you should use a filter. If you are always looking to filter by Id, dont pass it as a parameter but if it can change, add an other parameter. Lets say propName is staff and staffId is a new parameter as propNameId

Replace your pipe with this and dont forget to add a parameter in the html for the Id:

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform = (value:[],filterString:any,propName:any, propNameId):any => { 
        let inputValue = [];
        if(filterString === undefined || filterString === '' || 
           value.length == 0){
            return value;
        }
        inputValue = value.filter(item => {
            item[propName][propNameId] === filterString;
        })
        return inputValue;
    }      
}
```

The filter is going to return every item that has item.staff.staffId equal to whatever filterString is.